# Convert html table to iPhone table

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I have the following table in html:

[image: Soemthing]

What iOS element would I use to best represent the above? I know there's the `UITableViewController`, but how would I go about making it with multiple 'columns' and 'cells' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be just one UITableViewCell, which you then fill up with a label and 3 textfields / other UI-elements that you prefer. You can create this directly from the storyboard. Just set up a UITableView and add a Cell to it, which you then model into the layout, all cells of the table should have.

In the storyboard it would look something like this:
[image]

You can then create a custom cell, which is just a class of type UITableViewCell, and declare your IBoutlets there and connect it to the storyboard.